# Hide element if mouse leaves parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

I have two divs, the parent is let's say 100*100px small. When the user hovers the parent, a small popup with the content appears (absolute positioned to one side). This div is like a tooltip, and a child of the 100px div. Now, when the user leaves the parent div, the child should be hidden - even if the mouse leaves the parent 100px * 100px area.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily assign css styles to an element on parent's :hover

```
.tooltip {
    display: none;
}
:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution I'm using JQuery

```js
$('#parent').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('#child').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Child Text</div>
  Parent Text
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check below example.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: palegreen;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
#parent:hover #child {
  display: block;
}
#parent:hover #child:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    some content for the popup
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The content in my situation is leaving the parent. When I'm on the child, but not on the parent anymore and have left the green area, the child does not hide.